# define macro as linenumber

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, line-numbers

Is it possible to define a macro so it has the value of the line it is defined on?

I know about __LINE__ but it is expanding too late.

```
#define MYLINE __LINE__  // line 1
printf("%d\n", MYLINE);  // line 2
printf("%d\n", MYLINE);  // line 3
```

The above doesn't do what I want. I would want it to print 1 twice but it instead prints 2 and 3.

Comment: `puts(MYLINE)` would sent an `int` to `puts`, but `puts` expects a string (a pointer to a `char`).

Comment: [C11 Standard - 6.10.8 Predefined macro names](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.8) (Identical in C18 Standard) `"The values of the predefined macros listed in the following subclauses) (except for __FILE__ and __LINE__) remain constant throughout the translation unit.  ... None of these macro names, nor the identifier defined, shall be the subject of a #define or a #undef preprocessing directive."`

Answer (score 4):

A macro is like textual replacement (i.e. `MYLINE` is replaced with `__LINE__` everywhere). You won't be able to do that.

You can use a constant, though:

```
const int line = __LINE__;
printf("line %d\n", line);
printf("line %d\n", line);
```

Comment: Macros substitute preprocessor tokens, not text.

Comment: If you do not want to present the correct technical details, then say “A macro is like textual replacement,” which is true and at least alerts the reader that there is something more, rather than “A macro is just textual replacement,” which is false.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Happy?

Answer (score 3):

No, because:

- `__LINE__` is a macro name. (C 2018 6.10.8 1)
- “The preprocessing tokens within a preprocessing directive are not subject to macro expansion unless otherwise stated.” (C 2018 6.10 7)
- The specification for `# define` directives does not state otherwise. (C 2018 6.10.3)

So macro replacement can occur only where a macro is used subsequently; it cannot occur in the `# define` directive itself.

You can define constants with the line number, such as `static const int MyLine = __LINE__;`.